# With constructor autowiring Spring does not throw an exception when there are multiple implementation types

Tags: spring

There are interfaces `Work` and `You`. There are implementation types `WorkImpl` and `YouImpl` and `YouImpl2`.

I use constructor autowire to inject a `You` implementation instance in a `WorkImpl` instance.

Because there are multiple `You` implementations types, I thought Spring would throw an exception. But Spring instantiates an instance of one of the implementation types, in my case it was `YouImpl`. This is what I do not understand.

The configuration file is partly,

```
<bean 
    id="work" 
    class="my.test.own.spring_book.WorkImpl"
    autowire="constructor"
 >
    <property name="age" value="52"/>
    <property" name="name" value="Foo Bar"></property>
</bean>

<bean
    id="you"
    class="my.test.own.spring_book.YouImpl"
>
</bean>

<bean
    id="you2"
    class="my.test.own.spring_book.YouImpl2"
>
</bean>
```

`WorkImpl` has one constructor,

```
public WorkImpl(You you) {
    this.you=you;

}
```

Comment: It depends on the version of Spring (and java) you use. Spring does a by type auto wiring if multiple are found the name of the parameter is taken into account to match a bean name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few types of autowiring using configuration approach:

1. byName
2. byType
3. constructor
4. autodetect:- Similar to byType, but type applies to constructor arguments.

Spring container looks at the constructor of the beans on which autowire attribute is set to byType in the XML configuration file. It then tries to match and wire a property if its type matches with exactly one of the beans name in configuration file.

```
<bean id="you" class="my.test.own.spring_book.YouImpl">
</bean>

<bean id="you2" class="my.test.own.spring_book.YouImpl2">
</bean>
```

It will match with you as name of parameter used in constructor is you

```
public WorkImpl(You you) {
    this.you=you;

}
```

In order to avoid this you can use **autowire-candidate="false"** hence that bean will not take part in autowiring

```
<!-- This bean will not be injected-->
<bean id="you" class="my.test.own.spring_book.YouImpl" autowiring-candidate="false">
</bean>


<bean id="you2" class="my.test.own.spring_book.YouImpl2">
</bean>
```

Above is the answer of your question. But I will try to explain more so I can use this answer for future if I forget.

Now suppose you don't give id attribute to the bean or value of id attribute is different than the constructor parameter name.

```
    <bean id="you1" class="my.test.own.spring_book.YouImpl" autowiring-candidate="false">
    </bean>

    <bean id="you2" class="my.test.own.spring_book.YouImpl2">
    </bean>
```

- Spring container searches any bean with type You, yes found two. Do next step
- Spring container sees any bean with name(i.e id="you") you. No
- It throws exception Unsatisfied dependency Injection

  `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'work' defined in class path resource [autowire-contructor.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type
  [my.test.own.spring_book.You]: : No unique bean of type [my.test.own.spring_book.You] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [you1, you2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`

Comment: Thanks. So you mean that Spring looks for the type, and if he find more then one, Spring looks for the name of the argument of the constructor?

Comment: Yes, first it sees the type.....if more than one type are present then see for name. But if name doesnt matches the parameter name injected in constructor then throws Exception